# Directory not getting created

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata

I'm unsure why this code isn't working. It comes up that the directory exists, but then later on claims it doesn't.

```
+(NSString *)writeImageToFile:(UIImage *)image {
    NSLog(@"image 3: %@", image);
    NSData *fullImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Images/"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:nil]) {
        BOOL success = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
        NSLog(@"success 1: %i", success);
    }

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [JEntry generateUuidString]];
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    NSLog(@"file path: %@", filePath);
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [fullImageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to write to file with error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}
```

My NSLog:

```
image 3: <UIImage: 0x6972820>
file path: /var/mobile/Applications/5E25F369-9E05-4345-A0A2-381EDB3321B8/Documents/Images/3323E0F5-0B13-4CBA-898A-252212C65E2F.jpg
Failed to write to file with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x6987e20 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/5E25F369-9E05-4345-A0A2-381EDB3321B8/Documents/Images/3323E0F5-0B13-4CBA-898A-252212C65E2F.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x6977290 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory"}
```

Comment: Have you tried saving without Images in directory path. Do you want to create Images directory as well?

Comment: Can you post the code you used to create the directory "Images"? Also, can you post the result of the code I posted in my answer?

Comment: Hi did you get the solution to your problem?"The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory"  please share your solution if possible..thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my answer to your previous question, I will give you some code to help you debug this problem.

Try changing:

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:nil]) {
    BOOL success = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"success 1: %i", success);
}
```

into:

```
BOOL isDirectory = NO;
BOOL directoryExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDirectory];
if (directoryExists) {
    NSLog(@"isDirectory: %d", isDirectory);
} else {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    NSLog(@"success 1: %i", success);
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create directory with error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}
```

My guess is that "Images" is not a directory.

Comment: Where did you create "Images", can you post that code?  The code here looks correct, so I guess you created it somewhere else.

Comment: I didn't. I want to have it check to see if images exists before trying to write a file to it, and if it doesn't, it creates it.

Comment: Ah, that code you've posted works to create the directory. The next problem i have is it says `"The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory"` when i try and write a file to it.